# Expo Typescript won't build the project, no outDir is produced

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

I'm trying to get my typescript project to build. It has built successfully in the past with the same settings, but now it's not building even though it isn't showing any errors. I run:

```
npx tsc -p tsconfig.json
```

Where my `tsconfig.json` is:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "ES6",
    "target": "ES6",
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "./lib",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "react-native",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ],
  "extends": "expo/tsconfig.base"
}
```

No `lib` folder is produced at all.

My `src` folder contains several typescript files, as well as an index that exports the required components.

I'm really confused because my project structure and settings haven't changed at all yet `tsc` is no longer producing the `outDir` or any of the files when it worked before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expo is using `typescript` for typechecking only. Bundling files is done with [Metro bundler](https://facebook.github.io/metro/docs/getting-started#bundle). Thus [`expo/tsconfig.base`](https://docs.expo.io/guides/typescript/#base-configuration) has `noEmit` option set to `true`.

If you want to compile `js` files yourself you have to either run you command as:

```bash
npx tsc -p tsconfig.json --noEmit false
```

or to set `noEmit` option to `false` in your `tsconfig.json`. Don't forget to remove it back in you `tsconfig`. Or next time on build `expo` will run both `metro` bundling and tsc typecheck **and** tsc compilation.

As the last resort you may stop extending `expo/tsconfig.base` in your `tsconfig.json`. But do this only if you really know what you're doing.