# Where is the generated javascript made by Expo-CLI Metro?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, expo, metro-bundler

I have an Expo app that appears to fail on an Android emulator, but I can't seem to find the cause as of yet.  The error seems weird because it looks more like a syntax error which I presume would've been caught by typescript/eslint.  But it does not appear so, so it may be a package I am loading.  So what I am trying to ask is if there's a place in the file system that puts the assembled JavaScript file so I can hopefully use to to determine the errant module.

[image]

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68005577/562267

Comment: not really, because it compiles correctly using TSC it just fails on runtime in an Android emulator (not iOS)